# Using streams for parsing string from file

Tags: java, java-stream

I learn how to use java 8 API. I have a simple log file with the following contents:

```
SVF2018-05-24_12:02:58.917
NHR2018-05-24_12:02:49.914
FAM2018-05-24_12:13:04.512
KRF2018-05-24_12:03:01.250
SVM2018-05-24_12:18:37.735
MES2018-05-24_12:04:45.513
LSW2018-05-24_12:06:13.511
BHS2018-05-24_12:14:51.985
EOF2018-05-24_12:17:58.810
RGH2018-05-24_12:05:14.511
SSW2018-05-24_12:16:11.648
KMH2018-05-24_12:02:51.003
PGS2018-05-24_12:07:23.645
CSR2018-05-24_12:03:15.145
SPF2018-05-24_12:12:01.035
DRR2018-05-24_12:14:12.054
LHM2018-05-24_12:18:20.125
CLS2018-05-24_12:09:41.921
VBM2018-05-24_12:00:00.000
```

My goal is to parse it using streams. The desired output is the following:

```
[{SVF = [2018-05-24, 12:02:58.917]}, {NHR = [2018-05-24, 12:02:49.914]}...]
```

I already have the following:

```
public class FileParser {
    Stream<String> outputStream;
    public FileParser(String fileName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader();
        this.outputStream = fr.getStreamFromFile(fileName);

    public List<HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>> getRacersInfo(){
        return outputStream.map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.substring(0,3))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(???)); //Some code here which I cannot come up with.
    }
```

Any help appreciated. If you need any additional information feel free to ask, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: The 2018 field is not separated from the names, how do you want to parse them?

Comment: fixed-width fields it seems, at least OP uses `line.substring(0,3)` in his code

Comment: You can stream the lines using `java.nio.file.Files.lines(Path filePath)` but that won't automatically convert it to this JSON-like format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem: FileReader

FileReader is obsolete, don't use it. It's outdated API, and it's problematic, in that it presumes 'platform default encoding' which is a different way of saying 'a bug waiting to happen that no test will catch but that will blow up in your face later'. You never want 'platform default encoding', especially as a silent default.

There's a new File API, and it lets you specify encoding explicitly. Also, in the new File API, if you don't, UTF-8 is assumed which is a far saner default than 'platform default'.

### Problem: resources

Resources are objects that represent a resource that takes up OS-level handles. Files, network connections, database connections - those are some common examples of resources. The thing is **unlike normal objects, you MUST explicitly CLOSE those.** - if you don't, your VM will, eventually, crash. That means you can basically not put readers/inputstreams/outputstreams/writers in fields, ever, because how do you guarantee closing them? The only way is to make your own class a resource too (a thing that must explicitly be closed), which you can do, but is complicated, and not a good idea here.

You should never make resources unless you do so safely:

bad:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(..);
```

good:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(..)) {
    // use here
}
// it's gone here
```

It does require you to restyle things a bit. You have to open a resource, use the resource, and close it. This meshes well with pragmatic concerns: Resources are a drain on the OS, you don't want to keep em open any longer than you must, so 'open it, use it, and lose it' is the right mindset.

Furthermore, of course, resources as a concept are generally 'once-through-only'. for example, when reading a file, well, you read it, once, from the top to the bottom, and then any further attempts to read from it don't work anymore. So, in your example, the first time I call `getRacersInfo()`, it works. But the second time I call it, it won't, as the reader has now been consumed.

The solution to both problems is to do the reading in the constructor*.

*) See later - we're going to move this out of the constructor eventually, but that's a separate concern.

### Problem: Misunderstanding of responsibilities of constructors

This class is called a FileParser. So, it's *job* is to parse files (that, or, this class has a bad name). Generally, your constructors represent the 'data gathering' phase, not the 'do the job' phase. Therefore, parsing the file in the first place, in that constructor, is bad code style. You should not do this - your constructors should as a rule do as little as possible and definitely nothing tricky, such as opening files or actually parsing things. Again - the JOB of a FileParser is to parse files, and constructors should not do the job. They just set up the object so that it can do the job later.

The proper design, then, is:

```
public class FileParser {
    private final Path path;

    public FileParser(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public List<Map<String, List<String>> parseRacersInfo() {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            lines.map(.... parse the content here ....);
        }
    }
}
```

We have now:

1. Moved the 'job' part to a method that accurately describes the job.
2. Ensured the constructor is simple and just gathers information to do the job.
3. Safely use resources by applying the `try(){}` concept.
4. Use the new API (`java.nio.file.Files` and `java.nio.file.Path`).
5. Clarified our typing: That parameter to the constructor represents a path. If I call `new FileParser("Hello, IceTea, how's life?")` - that call makes no sense. `Path` is more descriptive than `String`, and if your method makes sense looking only at the types of the parameters? That's better than if you need to read the docs too.

### Problem: Not using java the way it wants to be used

Java is typed. Nominally so. Things should be stored in types that represent that thing. Thus, the string `2018-05-24_12:18:20.125` should be represented by an object that represents a time of some sort. Not a `List<String>` containing the string `2018-05-24` and `12:18:20.125`.

### Finally: How do I actually write the mapping?

Streams work by zooming in on a single element in the stream, and doing a series of operations on these elements, transforming them, filtering some out, etcetera. You cannot 'go back' in the process (once you map a thing to another thing, you can't go back to what it used to be), and you can't refer to other objects in your stream (you can't ask: Give me the item before me in the stream).

Thus, once you go: `line.substring(0, 3)`, you've thrown out the date, and that's a problem because we need that info. Therefore, you can't do that; not in a `.map()` operation, at any rate.

In fact, we can go straight to collecting the stream back into a map here - we need that entire string and we can derive the key from it  (`SVF`), and we need that entire string and we can derive the value from it (the date).

Let's write these conversion functions, and let's translate our string representing a time to a proper (also new in java 8) type for it: `java.time.LocalDateTime`:

```
Function<String, String> toKey = in -> in.substring(0, 3);

DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_FORMAT =
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
Function<String, LocalDateTime> toValue = in -> 
    LocalDateTime.parse(in.substring(3), DATETIME_FORMAT);
```

These are simple and we can test them:

```
assertEquals("VBM", toKey.apply("VBM2018-05-24_12:00:00.000"));
assertEquals(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 5, 24, 12, 0, 0),
    toValue.apply("VBM2018-05-24_12:00:00.000"));
```

Then we put it all together:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileParser {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_FORMAT =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);

    private final Path path;

    public FileParser(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Map<String, LocalDateTime> parseRacersInfo() throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            return lines.collect(Collectors.toMap(
                in -> in.substring(0, 3),
                in -> LocalDateTime.parse(in.substring(3), DATETIME_FORMAT)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new FileParser("test.txt").parseRacersInfo());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed and structured answer! I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    Map<String, List<LocalDateTime>> map = lines.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        line -> line.substring(0, 3),
        line -> LocalDateTime.parse(line.substring(3).replace('_', 'T')));
}
```

The `toMap` receives a key mapper and a value mapper. Here I keep the Stream of lines.

The resulting map is just a `Map`. Never provide an implementation, `HashMap` so the `collect` may return its own implementation. (If effect you could provide an implementation.)

(I used `Files.lines` which defaults to UTF-8 encoding, but you can add an encoding. The reason: Path is more generalized than File.)

Comment: An alternative to the `replace` would be a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS")`...

Comment: @deHaar better, but showing `parse` with the default pattern despite the ugly magic replace, seemed more instructive. And easier to remember.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS")` is a code smell - using DTF without a defined locale. With that specific smattering of formatting letters it most likely doesn't matter, but who really knows if every single last locale under the sun treats these the same? ofPattern defaults to 'platform default locale', which means it's untestable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Asmir\\Desktop\\input1.txt";
        Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            map = stream
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.substring(0,3), s -> Arrays.asList(s.substring(3).split("_"))));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```